# Python: Iterate dictionary that has set() as its value

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have dictionary where values are python sets, When I iterate without properly handling the sets, this is what I get.

```
Press Enter to continue...
Kunnskap set([])
Samfunn set([])
Helse set([])
Natur set([])
Geografi set([])
Teknologi set([])
Historie set([])
Dagligliv set([])
Personer set([])
Kommunikasjon set([])
Kultur set([])
```

and this is out I did, but I was looking within the value how can I iterate to get the set print out for each key. But sets doesn't have index so I cant iterate. What would be the best solution to print the set while iterating...?

```
for key, value in topLevelCatTree.iteritems():
    print key,
    for item in value:
        print item
```

Answer (score 4):

> But sets doesn't have index so I cant iterate.

Sure you can:

```
>>> x = set(range(10))
>>> x
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> iter(x)
<setiterator object at 0x0196C128>
>>> for y in x: print y
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The problem must be somewhere else.